# How do I call a method in the main thread and terminate the other thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading

So I am starting a thread which sorts a list, upon completion it should call the 'completedSorting()' method in my controller. Now I fear that just calling the method will lead to the method being executed in the other thread. I am decently good at C#, but threading is a new concept for me.

I would just return the thread but when I run multiple sortings at once this will just lead to confuson I reccon, hence I want them to call the 'completedSorting' Method

controller:

```
        public void StartAlgorithm(Algorithm algorithm)
        {
            // check listOfArrays
            if (listManager.arrayList.Count == 0)
            {       
                int[] newArray = CreateArray(algorithm.currentListLength);
                listManager.arrayList.Add(newArray);
                listManager.currentBiggestList = newArray.Length;
                Thread thread = new Thread(() => algorithm.SolveAlgorithm(newArray, algorithm));
                thread.Start();
```

bubblesort:

```
        public override void SolveAlgorithm(int[] arr, Algorithm algorithm)
        {
            int temp = 0;

            for (int write = 0; write < arr.Length; write++)
            {
                for (int sort = 0; sort < arr.Length - 1; sort++)
                {
                    if (arr[sort] > arr[sort + 1])
                    {
                        temp = arr[sort + 1];
                        arr[sort + 1] = arr[sort];
                        arr[sort] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
            CompletedAlgorithmLog newlog = new CompletedAlgorithmLog(filteredArray, algorithm);
            this.controller.OnCompletedArray(newlog);
```

the last line is where I need to alter some code, I reccon I would have to return after doing something like mainthread=>completedSorting, but I do not know exactly how.

Comment: Have you considered using something like BackgroundWorker (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker ) rather than creating threads directly?

Comment: @Chris I am aware that my approach might not be very efficient here, but since I want to learn about threading this is the thing I am trying to do

Comment: Cool. I raised it as a possibility just in case you were unaware of it. Quite often when doing threading there are tools like this that mean you don't have to write the more complex code and let the code other people have already written deal with it so you can do threading without needing to understand all the subtleties. :) I'm not knowldegable enough on using threads directly to want to try to tackle this question though I'm afraid.

Comment: Re, "Now I fear that just calling the method will lead to the method being executed in the other thread." True! a method call always happens in the thread that calls the method. But why is that a problem? Does it really _matter_ which thread calls `completedSorting(...)`? Almost always, if you want Y to happen after X is finished, the _best_ way to accomplish that is to have the same thread do X and then do Y.

Comment: @SolomonSlow CompletedSorting() is a main thread and will go on to create a new list for the sorting algorithm for it to sort, and since I have 2 algorithms sorting in different threads I feel like this will create a lot of unnecessary threads IF not break it

Comment: You said in your question that `completedSorting` was a method. Which is it? Is it a method or is it a thread? Either way, I'll stand by what I said: If you need your program to do X and then (and _only_ then) do Y; then the best way to accomplish that is to have one thread that does X and then does Y.  How you make doing X and doing Y "safe" in a program where other threads that may be interested in operating on the same data is the basic problem that we all have to solve every time we write multi-threaded code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Task Parallel library and use Task Continuation

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task
.Run(() => 
{
    StartAlgorithm(algorithm);
})
.ContinueWith(()=>{

  CompletedAlgorithmLog newlog = new CompletedAlgorithmLog(filteredArray, algorithm);
            this.controller.OnCompletedArray(newlog);

});
```

it will run the agorithm on different thread from threadpool and once it completes will execute code inside continueWith.